# Xero Payroll AU API: when I post a new EarningsLines item all existing EarningsLines items are removed

Tags: xero-api

Using MS Power Automate.
I am trying to post an additional EarningsLines item into the existing EarningsLines array in a PaySlip `https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/PaySlip/{PaySlipID}` But instead of adding a new item my entry seems to be replacing all items.

Method: `POST`  
URI: `https://api.xero.com/payroll.xro/1.0/PaySlip/{PaySlipID}`  
Body:

```html
[
  {
    "EarningsLines": [
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "3xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx3",
        "RatePerUnit": 44,
        "NumberOfUnits": 7.6
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The existing array:

```html
    "EarningsLines": [
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx1",
        "RatePerUnit": 65.7894,
        "NumberOfUnits": 38
      },
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "2xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx2",
        "FixedAmount": 384.62
      }
    ],
    "LeaveEarningsLines": [],
```

is replaced with

```html
    "EarningsLines": [
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "3xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx3",
        "RatePerUnit": 1,
        "NumberOfUnits": 7.6
      }
    ],
    "LeaveEarningsLines": [],
```

But what I actually want is

```html
    "EarningsLines": [
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "1xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx1",
        "RatePerUnit": 65.7894,
        "NumberOfUnits": 38
      },
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "2xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx2",
        "FixedAmount": 384.62
      },
      {
        "EarningsRateID": "3xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx3",
        "RatePerUnit": 65.7894,
        "NumberOfUnits": 7.6
      }
    ],
    "LeaveEarningsLines": [],
```

Please forgive my formatting, I couldn't find directions for inserting JSON into the post.